# Не запускается контейнер ( docker )

Tags: docker

Открываю приложение докера
Дальше создаю image: docker build -t area:env .
Дальше смотрю, что у меня создался image:

```
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
area         env       a8467548b037   5 minutes ago   1.31GB
node         latest    58dff30642de   9 days ago      943MB
```

Запускаю контейнер от этого image: docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --rm --name areacontainer area:env

Выдается id контейнера:

```
6836c59b4c1382bb3e6da74ad93b4428288e3a01e2f8bdf7f1c684a8a247d7e8
```

Я предполагаю, что контейнер запущен, но по факту нет.
Мой Dockerfile:

```
FROM node 

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

RUN npm install

COPY . .

ENV PORT 3000

EXPOSE $PORT

CMD ['npm', 'start']
```

Контейнер просто не запускается на маке, хотя когда я делаю тоже самое на пк на windows, то все работает. В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: что значит "не зпускается"? выдает какую-то ошибку? вы логи контейнера проверял или контейнер вообще не создается?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что когда я пишу docker ps - я должен увидеть запущенный контейнер. Его нету. Если при запуске я уберу флаг --rm то я увижу, что контейнер не запущен но он есть:  docker ps -a.

Comment: docker ps -a отображает все контейнеры (включая те что остановились, например из-за ошибки), запустите его без --rm и посмотрите логи через docker logs <container_name_or_id>, или запустите с флагами вместо -d поставе -it тогда будет выводить прямо в консоль, возможно это покажет причину

Comment: выдало [npm,: not found. Не понимаю почему он не нашел npm..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять `CMD` в `Dockerfile` на:

```
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Т.е. заменить `'` на `"`.

Документация:

> The exec form is parsed as a JSON array, which means that you must use double-quotes (“) around words not single-quotes (‘).

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd